# How to Create a Foreign Key from a Table to a Custom Datatype

Tags: oracle, database-design, user-defined-types, data-integrity, object-relational-model

Working with Oracle Express 11g, learning the interactions for object-relational databases.

Running into trouble while trying to create a foreign key from a normal table, to a table of a custom object (customers)

The customer object is as follows (`customer_id NUMBER, fname VARCHAR2, lname VARCHAR2`), for our setup, we wish to join a table Applications via `customer_id NUMBER`. Within the SQL Workshop, selecting the customers table is not even an option, and we cannot find syntax to manually create this relationship.

Any experts have some clues to help figure this one out?

Answer (score 1):

```
create or replace type customer is object
(
    customer_id NUMBER,
    fname VARCHAR2(100),
    lname VARCHAR2(100)
);
/

create table customers of customer
(
    constraint customer_pk primary key(customer_id)
);

create table applications
(
    application_id number,
    customer_id number,
    constraint applications_fk1 foreign key (customer_id)
        references customers(customer_id)
);
```